# Selenium click on next page button until disappears

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a website where I want to click on the "next page" until it reaches the last where the "next page" button is not there anymore. I have successfully **scraped** the first page with all the elements I need plus located the button. I can make the code ugly like placing sleep, and control-c control-v the same for loop again I'm looking for some better way of doing

```
try:
    for x in range (len(price)):
        print(price[x].text, location[x].text, area_size[x].text)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    print("QUITTING!")
    driver.quit()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()

next_page_button.click()
time.sleep(10)

try:
    for x in range (len(price)):
        print(price[x].text, location[x].text, area_size[x].text)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    print("QUITTING!")
    driver.quit()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

This does work but I got 14 next page buttons I have to click and it changes.. Is there an easier way to create a foor loop with an if condition let's stay if

`next_page_button.size = 0` ( I assume it reached the last page) my for loop stops?

Comment: _Is there an easier way to create a foor loop with an if condition let's stay if

next_page_button.size = 0 ( I assume it reached the last page) my for loop stops?_ Yes, most likely. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

You can have an infinite while loop constantly clicking the next page button, then break the loop when you can't find the button anymore.

```
try:
    while True:
        for x in range (len(price)):
            print(price[x].text, location[x].text, area_size[x].text)
        next_page_button.click()
        time.sleep(10)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    print("QUITTING!")
    driver.quit()
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
```

Also, rather than simply adding a 10 second wait for the page to load, you can implement a WebDriverWait object. This will continue once the target element has loaded, or until the timeout is reached. More info here: https://pythonbasics.org/selenium-wait-for-page-to-load/